# embed vlc player in HTML

Tags: html, video-streaming, vlc

i am trying to embed vlc player in a web page. what is the best way to do it.
actually i have to stream a video file using vlc and show it on  the web page so that 
other users logging to my site could see that video.
i have tried various snippts but unable to embed it. any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 9):

HTML way, make sure when u install VLC, u install Mozilla plug-in or ActiveX control stuff for (FF, IE or Chrome)

```
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"  width="100%"  height="100%" id="vlc" loop="yes" autoplay="yes" target="http://10.1.2.201:8000/"></embed>
```