# How to disable Firefox default PDF viewer / Plugin using asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox, pdf, plugins

I need to disable Firefox default PDF.js viewer through javascript (or) asp.net. I found one non-programmatic solution in Firefox options:

Options--> Application-->**Content type Portable document Format action default preview in firefox**

There I can change it to use Adobe Acrobat Reader, but how can we do this in code? 
**How can we get the Firefox browser Applications Action in java script code.**

Comment: why do want to do this. And how it is related to `asp.net`.

Comment: In my website have fillable pdf documents, so i opened pdfs using adobe acrobat in browser and send the mail through asp.net, in chrome i handled "chrome pdf viewer" in javascript to disable and enable adobe ,  but not handle in pdf.js plugin in firfox

Comment: If that was possible, that would be a reason not to use that browser.

Comment: That is website that can be browse in any browser.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you send the following header with the response containing the PDF:

```
Content-Disposition: Attachment
```

The browser will treat it as a file download instead of a document to display, which when opened will open with the users default PDF viewer.

Comment: Note that this approach will not allow you to embed the PDF file on a webpage.

Comment: Thank s for giving response, i wrote the above code it will ask to download the file and open adobe reader , but i have to open browser only (Nexttab), it is a fillable form , user fill the data and click the button send the details to mail, this operation not working in download pdfs

Answer (score -1):

the short answer is you cant, at least on remote users pcs, pretty much all browsers will flag that activity as malicious (think about how you'd feel if someone changed the program used to store your passwords).

you could maybe require the use of a pdf plugin in the same way you can require the use of flash.

rails would be a far better choice than asp.net in this case btw.

Comment: -1 Suggestions of the kind "use programming language X instead of Y" are subjective and not very useful. About being able or not to configure the default PDF reader, I do not see why this should be restricted. For example for video streaming you are free to specifically [embed VLC player](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120027/embed-vlc-player-in-html), flash or Windows Media player on your HTML page. There is nothing "malicious" about it.

Comment: Can you explain why you think rails would be better here? As far as I know rails sucks.