PDF uploaded within a folder downloads when viewed on phone browser - I want to change that to View
Noticed that when I click on a direct link to a PDF (mysite.com/resource/flyer.pdf) on my phone it downloads and then gives an option to view (Would you like to open the downloaded file?) instead of just opening the PDF in the browser itself.
However, this doesn't happen on desktop browser where it directly open in the browser.
I looked around and see that this has to do with response headers but I am not sure where and how to add or edit them.
The PDF file is the only thing in the folder.
I am on a litespeed server BTW.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393665/embed-the-pdf-in-a-webpage-without-using-the-built-in-pdf-viewer

Thank you @DarkBee but I want to use the direct link to the PDF without using Google Drive viewer and still be able to view the PDF in the browser without it downloading first.

Which is not possible on mobile browers - reference
