# IP camera multicast stream on web

Tags: html, network-programming, video-streaming, multicast, ip-camera

We are developing a project and a part of this project is showing live preview on web page. I should use multicast stream because there will be too many clients and none of them will directly connect to camera. I want to use multicast property of camera and no need to increase network traffic. I want to this very simple, I mean I want to show the stream on html img tag or something like this and give the source path (for ex : ) multicast IP address of the camera. I googled and could not find any clear solution. By the way I want to support all browsers so html img tag I prefered. I do not want to embed any video stream plugin because cross platform supporting. I need ideas or suggestion and a clear example. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways,
you can directly insert rtsp link inside your webpage using vlc plugin or Quicktime plugin, or you can make a server to read stream from the camera(may be using nodejs or gstreamer or opencv etc) and broadcast it to a http ip or send it in base64 images to webport and on the website you can read it using websockets, socket.io library

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your answer, but I do not want make a connection to IP camera, I can do it with user name and password and IP address of camera. I want to set IP camera to send stream via multicast address and capture and show the stream on my web page

Comment: it depends which camera are you using, i have used Axis, samsung, honeywell, oncam, etc some of these have https streaming link but most of them dont have any, if it has you can use video tag but if not you have to integrate a plugin tag, like vlc
**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120027/embed-vlc-player-in-html**

Comment: rtsp link usually like
rtsp://user:pass@ip:554/profile

Comment: Brand of camera is Dunlop 1032F. As you said most of them have http and https streaming but as I mentioned before I will not make a connection to IP cam with user name and password. I will set camera multicast streaming on and each client will capture the same data of live preview. Client side will have a plugin or I do not know exactly how to show multicast stream on web page. By the way, my camera's multicast IP address is 239.255.0.1 and what will be the source address (fqdn) of multicast stream. If you help me I will be very happy..

Comment: I intergrated a plugin and can display the stream but I can only display when source address contains the IP address of IP camera. When I open more than 10 browser windows it cannot display. The point is I want to achieve, using multicast property and multicast IP address of IP camera many browser should display the stream that the bandwidth supported.

Comment: multicast config is on the camera side, see at cam config and setup multicast address, later you can connect your clients to that multicast address